# Which is Best For Hosting My Vb.Net Windows ERP Application

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a windows server 2008 and sql server 2005 and my application is windows based.

I have created a wcf service in my application for sending SMS.

I have a server with internet connection and have 50 pc's in the network.

They dont have internet connection, but they want to send sms through server.

I made the wcf service for sending sms. This service is working good on server.

1. Which hosting is best for my application ?
2. How to access this service on client machine ?

Answer (score 0):

1. [In IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)
2. Using a [pre-generated proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) or at runtime using [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)